# Why using ADB command 'settings put global preferred_network_mode' doesn't reflect the changes in Test Settings?

Tags: adb, mobile-network, command-line

I've been trying to search about changing network mode programmatically which was already answered, but I noticed that when using:

```
settings put global preferred_network_mode x
settings put global preferred_network_modex x
```

Changes doesn't reflect to the [Test settings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/tools_r22/src/com/android/settings/RadioInfo.java), which can be access through `*#*#4636#*#*`, and some device doesn't get the change in their phone signal literally after the command.

So question:

> Why using ADB command 'settings put global preferred_network_mode' doesn't
>   reflect the changes in Test Settings but **manually changing** the
>   network preference under Settings or the opposite changing from Test
>   settings using UI will reflect the change to each other.